# spring mvc 3.0 HTTP Status 404

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, spring-mvc

I know this type of questions were asked earlier here, and I have gone through many but couldn't find the solution I'm looking for....

I'm keep on getting "HTTP Status 404" for my test spring mvc 3.0 app. whenever I hit "`http://127.0.0.1:8080/com.test.andro/androTest1.jsp`" via browser. This is simple app. which should read the 1st line of text from a file and should return the content as response. 
Below are configuration files, can someone please figure it out what's going wrong here.

-------------------------------web.xml-------------------------------

```
<web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="2.4"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee 
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">

  <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>

  <servlet>
        <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <context-param>
    <param-name>log4jConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>WEB-INF/classes/log4j.properties</param-value>
  </context-param>

  <listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.util.Log4jConfigListener</listener-class>
  </listener>

</web-app>
```

--------------------------------- mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml --------------------------------------

```
 <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
        xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

        <context:component-scan base-package="com.test.andro" />



    </beans>
```

-----------------------------------------Controller---------------------------------------

```
   package com.test.controller;

    import java.io.BufferedReader;
    import java.io.File;
    import java.io.FileReader;

    import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;

    @Controller
    public class AndroController {

        @RequestMapping(value="/androTest1.jsp", method=RequestMethod.GET)
        @ResponseBody
        public String readFromTestFile() {

            File file = new File("\resources\test1.txt");

            try {

                BufferedReader bfr = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));

                return bfr.readLine();

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }

    }
```

I'm using actual tomcat server and not one from eclipse workspace.
So if I hit "`http://127.0.0.1:8080/`" I do get tomcat server page(guess my server is working properly) but get error if I hit project related URL as shown above.

It would be really helpful if someone can tell me what's wrong I'm doing here.

Thank you

Regards,

Harshad

Answer (score 0):

Your controller isn't currently being registered as a handler. You'll need to configure the MVC side of the application by declaring

```
<mvc:annotation-driven/>
```

in your servlet context configuration. Add a file named `mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml` as a Spring bean configuration and add that line to it. Don't forget the namespace declarations as well.

Comment: Hi Sotirios, Thanks for the quick reply really appreciate it. As you suggested, I have added <mvc:annotation-driven/> to mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml along with namespace, also the contextConfiguration was already there in web.xml which I posted in my question. But still no luck.....getting same error......thank you